# what is the recommended installation order for multi-boot OSes?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bootloader, esxi

When it comes to dual-boot of Windows and Linux on a hard disk, it is recommended to install Windows followed by Linux, for bootloader to identify both OS partitions.

What is the recommended installation order if (ESXi, Linux and Windows) or (ESXi and Linux) are involved?

Comment: I guess it will be: ESXi first, then if You have Windows second it is. Last is Linux and boot it all from GRUB. See also, somebody tried it already: http://www.highlyunsupported.com/2012/03/multiboot-esxi-5-windows-2008-r2-rhel-6.html